# Checkout an SVN repo and export to another server

Tags: svn

I'm trying to checkout an SVN repo and push it onto another remote repo while trying to maintain all the commit history.

Is doing the following the right way to go about it?

- svn co [url]
- svn export [new-url]

Make code changes, add new files, commit :-

- svn commit -m 'commit message'

However, im concerned that the commit would take place in `url` and not `new-url`. In order to make commits at `new-url` would I have to checkout the repo at `new-url` again and then commit?

Is this the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: If you want to maintain all the commit history, "svn co/commit/import/export" won't help. Have a look at "svnsync" instead or at "svnadmin dump/load" approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `svn export` creates **unversioned copy** of your Workin Copy, i.e: it can't be commited to anywhere, it doesn't containt any (needed) meta-information
2. svn-sync is really more natural way

But, if you **really want** to support mirror-repository by hand (I still recommend create mirror from data-dump of original), starting from *some-rev*, you **can** do it (hereinafter SRC and MIRROR are shorthands for "original" repo and "clone").

Starting point: you have SRC@SOME-REV, MIRROR@SOME-REV and  Working Copy of SRC

Workflow

1. Hack-hack-hack code
2. `svn ci -m "message"`
3. `svn relocate MIRROR`
4. `svn ci -m "message"`
5. `svn relocate SRC`
6. See p.1

Comment: @uki - If maintaing more than one mirror is a task, early or later DVCS will appear on scene ([some](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/hgsubversion/) can work even with SVN repositories semi-transparently)